# javafx.application.Application class in not not importing in eclipse

Tags: javafx

i have install java 8 and eclipse luna when i am trying to import javafx.application package it will not showing the Application class i have add jar called jfxrt but it is not working**

```
    import javafx.application.;
    public class FxExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: DId you mean `import javafx.application.Application;`?

Answer (score 0):

Please make yourself familiar with the JavaFX language and read at least the documentation about how to implement [Hello World, JavaFX Style](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm).

Since you are on eclipse instead of NetBeans, I rather suggest you get [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/) instead of trying to get it to work manually. Just download the package, install it and you're good to start developing.